# OpenCV Mouth & lips detection

Tags: objective-c, opencv, face-detection

I'm using OpenCV to do face detection (not recognition) and have succeeded with finding faces with `cvHaarDetectObjects()` with `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`

I then create a region of interest (ROI) of the bottom third of the face to find the mouth with `haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml` and it works OK.

I now need to find the lips in the mouth region. I want to be able to fill the lips with color (like lipstick) whether the mouth is closed or open. So I can get some sort of dataset telling me which pixels are skin, lips, and teeth (I don't need the teeth part, but it'd tell me if the mouth is open)

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: [Active Appearance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1iu__viJN8) may be a solution.

Comment: are you able to solve it out ?